# Is there regex to remove space and newline from xml input file

Tags: regex, xml, text-processing

I would like to change an xml which is in format

```
<input>My    
Input</input>

<input2>My 
input2</input2>
```

to

```
<input>My Input</input>
<input2>My input2</input2>
```

The input xml file has more than 10000 records with xml in the above format which breaks the software to work properly.

Need a regex to fix it in one stroke.

```
I tried ('//n','') but it is not functioning as expected
```

Comment: The new line character is “\n” and not “/n”.

Comment: Why do you need to do that with a regex, why not simply find and replace all newlines with nothing? Also what language are you using (please tag the question appropriately) as `('//n','')` is not a regex

Comment: @AD7six Because you'd end up with just one line combining all the lines in the text?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed what's wrong with that?

Comment: @AD7six Nothing. It's just not what the OP wants. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure, where in the question does it say that's a problem? Why _would_ it be a problem given it's xml? I didn't vote on your answer btw - but using a regex to do anything _if It's unnecessary_ is not a good practice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports Lookbehinds, you may use something like this:

```
(?<!>)(\s)*[\r\n]+
```

..and replace with `\1`.

This will match any number of new-line characters, preceded by zero or more other whitespace characters and *not* preceded by the `>` character. Then, it will replace them with a whitespace character (if present) or nothing.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIZiU3/1).

If Lookbehind is not supported, you may use:

```
([^>])(\s)*[\r\n]+
```

..and replace with `\1\2`.